# cURL error 60: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

Tags: php, ssl, curl, amazon-s3, laravel-5.1

this is not duplicate, and kindly, don't mark it -ve or duplicate as I've found no solution anywhere.

I'm trying to upload files to `S3` with `Laravel`'s built in `s3` driver, but getting the following error

> S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 159:
>   Error executing "PutObject" on "amazon.com/bucket/file.extension"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates.

So is there anyway to disable `SSL verification` exception just before uploading data to `S3`

Here is code snippet

```
$uploadFile = $this->_getFileToUpload($file);
Storage::disk('s3')->put($file, $uploadFile);
```

I just want to disable exception before `put` statement.

Thanks.

*PS*

versions that I'm using are:

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.3",
"rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.5.3",
"sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "^1.5",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0"
```

Comment: @Maks3w: no, that's not the duplicate of this question, as I'm using `s3` driver, not `Guzzle` or `curl` in my applcation

Comment: Your issue is with the settings of PHP.ini and if you read the error message S3 is using cURL. Just configure the CA in your php.ini

Comment: ok, and what if I just want to ignore this at all?

Comment: Why would you not fix the problem rather than try to suppress verification?